# F# and namespace

Tags: f#

I have an application, call it App1. It is mostly C#. I'm writing a dll in F#. It cointains a class, Class1. I want this class to belong to the App1 namespace.

If I add namespace App1 on the top of my .fs file, it complains that a namespace cannot contain values (I have some lets in my file).

If I add "module App1" under the namespace, it compiles, but I cannot access the namespace from outside. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simplest to separate out the class code from the freestanding functions -- I'd do something like

```
#light
namespace App1
open ModuleWithFunctionsIn

type Class1 = class
(* stuff goes here *)
end
```

and pull the free-standing functions in from a separate module

Answer (score 0):

I do not remember exact answer, but what I did is inspecting F# assemblies with .NET Reflector. Often this answers all questions like this.